# Check php array (with dates) if today's date exists (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: php, arrays, date, advanced-custom-fields

I am checking exception-dates against today’s date. If TRUE some code needs te be triggered…. but it always returns FALSE.

I’m certain that the output of both is in the exact same way (`Y-m-d` f.i. 2022-01-28). I even echoed both with good results.

I also believe both strings are real dates so why does the IF statement always returns FALSE??

```
function yl_opening_status_icon_shortcode() {

    if (have_rows('booking_settings_exceptions', 'booking_settings')) {

        while (have_rows('booking_settings_exceptions', 'booking_settings')) { the_row();

            $today_date         = date('Y-m-d'); // Today's date
            $exceptions         = get_sub_field('booking_settings_exceptions_date');
            $exception          = str_replace('/', '-', $exceptions);
            $whole_day          = get_sub_field('booking_settings_exceptions_whole_day');
            $reason             = get_sub_field('booking_settings_exceptions_reason');

            $exception_dates    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($exception)); // Array of dates

            if (in_array($today_date, $exception_dates)) {

                // This always returns false, even if it's true
                // echo $today_date and echo $exception_dates work and output does have same values 
                // and I believe there both set as real dates so why doesn't it pass here..?

            }

        }

    }

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Please post an example of the values of `get_sub_field('booking_settings_exceptions_date');`, in best case with multiple values. Your `$exception_dates` definitely doesn't contain an array, it is just "possible", that it contains a single timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the exceptions weren't real dates after all. With this addition everything works great:

```
$exception_date     = getDate($exception_dates);
```